# why we are using fm and trim in char functions

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Query #1

```
Select * 
from EMPLOYEE 
where trim( to_char(joining_date,'Month')) ='January';
```

Query#2

```
select * 
from employee 
where to_char(joining_date,'Month')='January';
```

Query #3

```
select * 
from employee 
where to_char(joining_date,'fmMonth')='January';
```

If I do first query I am getting answer.

If I do 2nd query I am not getting answer .

If I use fm in 3rd query I am getting answer

What is the reason behind this.

Comment: can you show demo data?

Answer (score 1):

Cause Oracle (I guess you're working with Oracle) adds blank spaces (padding) so that the results have always the same "size" (format) when formatting values.

Fake example, without trim or `fm` (oh, how nicely formatted is this !)

```
01 January   2015
12 September 2015
```

With `Fm` version or trim, you remove these "padding" spaces.

Fake example, with trim or `fm` (oh, that's ugly, but at least I don't have all these spaces)

```
1 January 2015
12 September 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

With FM (stands for format mask) prefix, you are applying the format_mask. This means that you are asking query engine that zeros and blanks are meant to be suppressed.

If you are asking why trim or FM then you should try running these two queries to understand it:

```
select length(trim(to_char(to_date('15052015', 'DDMMYYYY'), 'MONTH'))) from dual;
select length(to_char(to_date('15052015', 'DDMMYYYY'), 'MONTH')) from dual;
select length(trim(to_char(to_date('15092015', 'DDMMYYYY'), 'MONTH'))) from dual;
select length(to_char(to_date('15092015', 'DDMMYYYY'), 'MONTH')) from dual;
```

Since your NLS setting by default for NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE would be ENGLISH, May takes 3 characters while September takes 9 characters. Hence by default it will add 6 additional characters to May as well.

Comment: i was run the quries answers are 7(january) and 9 (september).But i  didn't understand my question.

Comment: Try run all 4 queries and observe the result. I tried explaining below the queries. even for May you will get length as 9 while if you trim you will see it as 3. So the output i expect is 3,9,9,9

Comment: yes you are right can you explain me why

Answer (score 0):

The `FM amodifier`, used in format models in the `TO_CHAR` function, control blank padding and exact format checking.
The `SQL TRIM()` removes leading and trailing characters(or both) from a character string.